# ASP.NET: Open File From URL

Tags: asp.net, .net, file

In ASP.NET, I have an XML file (within my project) that I would like to deserialize.  FileStream objects do not allow you to open a file via URL.

What is the easiest way to open the file so that I can deserialize it?

Answer (score 3):

If the file is within your project you just need to get the physical location of the file. You can use Server.MapPath("/yourfile.txt") to get the phyical location and then open it with a filestream.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [XmlDocument.Load(url)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx) method which will load an XML Document from a URL